# Cron not running on bootup Debian

Tags: cron, debian

Whenever I switch off my server, I need to start my cron service manually. I fired a command :-

```
sudo update-rc.d cron defaults
```

Upon firing the above command, it shows the following:-

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match cron Default-Stop values (none)
insserv: warning: script 'K02printer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K02autossh_tunnel_x2' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'printer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'autossh_tunnel_x2' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

When I restart the server and `pgrep cron` , no integer is being displayed. I need to `sudo service cron start` to start my cron manually.

**How do I start the cron service on bootup.**

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the service got disabled.  You need to re-enable it with "`update-rc.d cron enable`".  That should do the trick.

The other warnings are about different init scripts which lack their LSB header.  You should look into those, too.

Comment: Will enabling solve the problem, I mean if the server re-starts again, will it enable itself on bootup?? PS: Though I've implemented it, I cannot check because its in a live enviorment, and I cannot restart my server without the prior consent of our customer.

Comment: You can check the runlinks before you do the update-r.cd enable call by doing "`ls /etc/rc*/*cron`" and take a look at what links are actually there.  After you did the enable call there should see S links in the rc2.d through to rc5.d directories, and I suspect that those weren't there before you did the enable call.

Comment: I used this in reverse, to ```update-rc.d cron disable``` and it worked well.